# Moving to microsoft blend

Tags: visual-studio, blend

I am developing a solution in Visual Studio.
The solution includes several projects, some are WPF projects and some are console projects.
Is it better to develop the solution in Microsoft Blend.
What are the risks (if any) for moving to Microsoft Blend?
Thanks,
Ilan

Comment: Blend is primarily used for the View part of MVVM/WPF projects. Which I guess it's possible, VS has significantly more support for developing code. I don't even know if Blend is actually getting meaningful updates anymore.

Comment: As I understood the blend uses the compiler\envs as the Visual Studio so if I keep the Visual Studio updated would it keep blend updated?.

Comment: My next question is about customization. My application is not GUI focused (That mean that I don't use fancy GUI controls etc'). Does using blend can make it easier to customize the controls?